# htaccess RewriteRule url frendly searches

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a `.htaccess` file with this in it:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?page=search&search=$1
```

So basically it sends URLs like this:

```
url.net/search/this
```

To this:

```
url.net/?page=search&search=this
```

But when I send it a URL like:

```
url.net/search/this+search
```

I get an error returned as it doesn't know how to deal with `+search` bit.

Is there a way I can get it to include the `+` between words when the user clicks search?

I want it so that if the user types `i+want+this+or+that` or `this+is+what+i+want+to+find`, so no mater how long it is, it knows how to handle the parse to `$_GET['search']` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just include it in the regex...just remember to escape it,

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z\+]+)$ index.php?page=search&search=$1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex for the rewire rule:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([a-zA-Z].+)$ index.php?page=search&search=$1
```

Note the `.` before the `+` sign. Works as a regex here [on this live PHP regex site](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/2UO). Yes, I know this is an Apache rewrite rule & PHP has no role at this stage, but basic regex logic should remain the same.

Comment: That works as well :) Doesn't only include "+" though but all characters!